# Ricci curvature on sphere

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from Hamilton's Three manifolds with positive Ricci curvature. I know why $R(u,v,u,v)>0$. Since the secional curvature of sphere is positive, I have
$$
\frac{R(u,v,u,v)}{|u\wedge v|^2} = K(u,v)>0
$$
therefore, I agree $R(u,v,u,v)>0$. But, why $R(u,u)>0$ on sphere ?

> [image]

Comment: First you cannot deduce $R(u,v,u,v)>0$ just from $K>0$ in general. Second Ricci curvature is sum of sectional curvature. [see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/234921/272127)

Comment: Since it is just the sphere, why don't you just calculate and check?

Comment: @C.F.G  Sorry, why I can't deduce $R(u,v,u,v)>0$ from $K>0$ ?  I fail to find my mistake.

Comment: @lanse7pty: you can ask this as a separate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u_1\in T_pM$ with $|u_1|=1$ and extend it to an onb $u_1,\dots,u_n$. Then

$$R(u_1,u_1)=
\sum_{i=1}^nR(u_1,u_i,u_1,u_i)=\sum_{i=2}^nR(u_1,u_i,u_1,u_i)=\sum_{i=2}^nK(u_1,u_i)>0$$